# event input dialog flowtter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialogflow-es

I want to raise a Dialogflow event from the flutter app using dialog flowtter. There is an exception. **400 field input not set**. what can I do?

```
DetectIntentResponse response = await dialogFlowtter.detectIntent(
      queryInput: QueryInput(
          eventInput:
              EventInput(name:"username",languageCode: "en", parameters:{username: user!.uid})),
      audioConfig: OutputAudioConfig(),
    );

Unhandled Exception: Exception: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field input not set., (400)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was a bug from the dialog flowtter library. it is now changed in version 0.3.2